# What is the language used in LateX?

Tags: sourcecode, learning, tutorials

I'm writing a book with LateX since few months ago and I used some blocks of code as black box for me because I don't know the language of LateX, and I can't solve some problems because of my ignorance on the subject. Where can I find documentation on the programming language of LateX in order to understand how it works?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

Comment: Interestingly, that list did not include the TeXbook by Knuth.  LaTeX is based on TeX much as C++ is based on C, and most LaTeX manuals don't cover the base TeX commands.

Comment: Perhaps more helpful: [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668)

Comment: @JohnKormylo But is logical, because it is like driving a car. Although know a few things about the engine (such as it need  gasoline and oil from time to time) usually does not hurt, what a novice really need in the first practice is how you use the steering wheel and where is  the brake pedal, not how to change the spark plug, that however will be a must for a Paris-Dakar racer.